# Material UI dark mode and light mode using react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

**Instead of switch component I want to use Light Mode and Dark Mode button on Navbar.js and Publish website need to be green on light and change color on dark mode but it not changing**
I want to use two button on Navbar instead switch component and publish button background should be green on light mode and change color on dark mode.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Body from './Body';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import { makeStyles, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { createMuiTheme, CssBaseline, Switch } from '@material-ui/core';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
      width: "1440px",
      display: "flex",
  }
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: darkMode ? "dark" : "light", 
    }
  })

  const handleDarkMode = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkMode);
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline>
        <Switch onChange={handleDarkMode} value={darkMode} />
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Sidebar />
          <Body />
        </div>
      </CssBaseline>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Sidebar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        width: "260px",
        // border: "1px solid black"
    }
}));

function Sidebar() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <h1>Hi</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Body.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Builder from './Builder';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        width: "1180px",
        height: "100%",
        padding: "15px",
        // border: "1px solid black",
        // backgroundColor: "#f4f5f7",
    }
}));

function Body() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Navbar />
            <Builder />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Body
```

Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Brightness4Icon from '@material-ui/icons/Brightness4';
import Brightness7Icon from '@material-ui/icons/Brightness7';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import OpenInNewIcon from '@material-ui/icons/OpenInNew';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-between"
    },
    leftNav: {
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderRadius: "12px",
    },
    lightMode:{
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        border: "none",
        fontSize: "15px",
        padding: "10px",
        borderRadius: "12px",
        textTransform: "none",
    },
    darkMode:{
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        border: "none",
        fontSize: "15px",
        padding: "10px",
        borderRadius: "12px",
        textTransform: "none",
    },
    rightNav: {
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        marginTop: "10px",
    },
    preview:{
        marginRight: "15px",
        textDecoration: "none",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        fontSize: "13px",
        "&:hover": {
            textDecoration: "underline",
        }
    },
    publish:{
        marginLeft: "15px",
        textDecoration: "none",
        backgroundColor: "#02AA02",
        color: "white",
        padding: "12px",
        paddingLeft: "18px",
        paddingRight: "18px",
        borderRadius: "18px",
        fontSize: "13px",
    },
    lightClick: {
        backgroundColor: "red",
    },
    icons: {
        marginRight: "8px",
    }
}));



function Navbar() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <div className={classes.leftNav}>
                <Button variant="text" color="default" className={classes.lightMode} onClick={classes.lightClick}>
                    <Brightness7Icon className={classes.icons} />
                    Light mode
                </Button>
                <Button variant="text" color="default" className={classes.darkMode} onClick={classes.darkClick}>
                    <Brightness4Icon className={classes.icons} />
                    Dark mode
                </Button>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.rightNav}>
                <a href="#" className={classes.preview}>
                    Preview in new tab
                    <OpenInNewIcon fontSize="small" style={{fontSize: "15px", marginLeft: "5px"}} />
                </a>
                <a href="#"className={classes.publish}>Publish Website</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Navbar
```

Builder.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Grid, Paper, Tabs, Tab } from '@material-ui/core';
import DesktopMacIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DesktopMac';
import TabletMacIcon from '@material-ui/icons/TabletMac';
import PhoneIphoneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/PhoneIphone';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    /* hidden preview's nav tab on mobile devices */
    previewTab: {
        // [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        //     display: 'flex',
        // },
        // display: 'none',
    },
    builder: {
        width: '100px',
        height: '100px',
        color: "white",
        display: 'inline'
    },
    webPreviewContainer: {
        textAlign: 'center',
    },

}));

const Builder = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Grid container direction='row' justify='center' alignItems='flex-start' spacing={4}>
            <Grid
                container item xs={12} md={12} lg={10}
                justify='center' direction='row'
                spacing={2}>
                <Grid
                    item xs={12}
                    justify='center'
                    className={classes.previewTab}>
                    <Paper style={{width: "100%", marginTop: "20px",}}>
                        <Tabs
                            indicatorColor='primary'
                            textColor='primary'
                            centered
                            variant="fullWidth"
                        >
                            <Tab icon={<DesktopMacIcon />} label='Desktop' />
                            <Tab icon={<TabletMacIcon />} label='Tablet' />
                            <Tab icon={<PhoneIphoneIcon />} label='Mobile' />
                        </Tabs>
                    </Paper>
                    
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
};

export default Builder;
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/dry-wood-scjnn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark